# SEO URL Anchor and string instead of query

Tags: seo

Is this URL meant to be good for SEO, or is it just weird?

http://www.clarks.co.uk/c/mens-sale#Sort-is-price-by-descending-and-pagesize-is-200-and-page-is-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why # ?

you can easily use this format:

... /mens-sale-Sort-is-price-by-descending-and-pagesize-is-200-and-page-is-1

and better is:

... /mens-sale-Sort-is-price-by-descending-and-pagesize-is-200-and-page-is-1.html

or if it's hard for you to handle these types of url, you can use this:

... /mens-sale/Sort-is-price-by-descending-and-pagesize-is-200-and-page-is-1.html